# can not login with flutter in graphql with python backend

Tags: http, post, dart, flutter

i try to login in in graphql API in Django backend.i send the request and get the session ID from API but when i try to use that session ID in another post requests i get the access denied error. i think maybe flutter device can not stay login or post requests are just single use because try this function from postman and get true answer. so what should i do?
here is my login request:

```
static Future<String> Login(String user,String password) async {
  var url = "my url";

  var request = "mutation{logIn(username:${'"'+user+'"'}, password:${'"'+password+'"'}){result session error}}";
  http.Response res = await http.post(url, body:{
    "query": request
  }) ; // post api call
  Map login = json.decode(res.body);
  print(res);
  print(res.headers);
  print(login);
  var RawData = login['data']['logIn'];
  if (RawData['result']){
    return(RawData['session']);
  }else{
    return '';
  }
}
```

and my check session request:

```
static Future<String> checkSession(String session) async {
  var url = "my url";

  print('session is here: '+ session);

  http.Response res = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {'sessionid':session},
    body:{
      "query":"mutation{checkSessionValidation{result,error}}"
    },) ;

  Map state = json.decode(res.body);
  print(res.headers);
  print('send validator :' + res.body);
  var RawData = state['data'];
  print("raw data is: "+RawData);
  return RawData;
}
```